# Line intesection in 3D with uncertainties

Tags: geometry, numeric

I have to compute the intersection of two lines in 3D space.

This qestion itself has already been adressed.

The reason why I am posting is that the lines both come with some uncertainties
in their direction.

This is represented on the figure below. Each line comes with its own coordinate axes. Uncertainty is represented by a matrix covariance, this one is generally diagonal with the azimut and elevation variance as elements. The uncertainty is geometrically represented by a conic with the line as center axe and delimited by the standard deviation (square of variance).

[image]

So, ideally, what I would like to compute is the intersection volume between these conics. Whether these ones really intersects depend on the implicit probability distributions. If you assume them to be gaussian, the intersection will always exist except that if line directions are very distant, it will have a very poor probability.

This is what I would like to assess numerically : get the volume intersection and its probability.

I assume the probability distributions of both lines to be independent.

For the moment, what I figured out is to compute the distance between both lines.
If this one is zero, they really intersect. This distance is a segment perpendicular to both lines. My guess is that the middle point of this segment will represent the point with best probability for lines to intersect.

Then, I would assume the probability distribution around that point to be gaussian and compute its covariance matrix numerically.

Do you agree with this method ? or think there would be a better way ?

Regards

Comment: This seems, for the moment, to be less about programming and more about the math. So please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: It's very close to programming, computational geometry, but you are right, I should have asked this question on the Mathematics Stack Exchange. I can post it again on this very forum or maybe an administrator can move my post (?)

Comment: I doubt that you will get a spatial Gaussian around a point with that. [Math.se] is really the better site for this. Delete your question here and ask it again there. Btw, with Gaussians, the intersection volume will be theoretically infinite because Gaussians are not locally supported - in theory.